# reusing Color type (reset color) in java

Tags: java

Is there any possible way to reuse the same Color type object without creating a new one? Because I think creating a new Color object is slowing the program down if the color is changed frequently.

something like this:

```
//passing Graphics g into the function
int color_setting=1;
while(1)
{
    Color cl=new Color(color_setting,0,0);
    g.setPaint(cl);
    //the rest of drawing
    color_setting=(color_setting+1)%256;
}
//is there a way to reset the color of old cl without always creating a new Color object?
```

Ok I'm posting the whole code here. Sry it's a little bit messy:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;
class compo extends JComponent
{
    static int color,dir;
    {
        color=0;
        dir=1;
    }
    Toolkit kit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension sz=kit.getScreenSize();
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){return new Dimension(sz.width/2,sz.height/2);}
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
        float x=255;
        int count=255;
        while(count!=0)
        {
            color=color+dir;
            if(color%128==0)
               dir=-dir;
            Color temp_color=new Color(color+64,0,0);
            Line2D line=new Line2D.Double(0.0,x,sz.width,x);
            g2.setPaint(temp_color);
            x--;
            count--;
            g2.draw(line);
        }
    }

}

public class hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    SimpleFrame frame=new SimpleFrame();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    class temp implements ActionListener
                    {
                        Timer timer;
                        Toolkit kit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                        Dimension sz=kit.getScreenSize();
                        SimpleFrame frame;
                        public temp(SimpleFrame _frame)
                        {
                            frame=_frame;
                        }

                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                        {
                            timer.stop();
                            frame.setTitle("this is the frame!");
                            frame.add(new compo());
                            frame.pack();
                            timer.start();
                        }
                        public void storing(Timer timer)
                        {
                            this.timer=timer;
                        }
                    }
                    ActionListener test=new temp(frame);
                    Timer t=new Timer(0,test);
                    ((temp)test).storing(t);
                    t.start();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
class SimpleFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH=300;
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT=200;
    public SimpleFrame()
    {
        setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH,DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got some code we can look at? What have you tried so far?

Comment: To answer directly:  yes.  To be more specific, I'd need to see what you're doing in your program to cause you to create so many of them.

Comment: I only want to change the color of one color type object after it's been created.

Comment: sry about the frequent editing just done

Answer (score 2):

`java.awt.Color` is immutable class. You have to create a new `Color` instance if you need a new color, there is no other way. However, creating a new `Color` will not slow you down because you typically don't create a new `Color` in a tight loop like in your code. You create a color, do something with it and then create another color for some other purpose and do some other actions. In that kind of a real case just creating new color on need basis will not at all slow down the code!

Adding this after few messages exchanges with the author of the question:

It is definitely not slowing down after some time. Do this to verify:Add time logging in `paintCompoment` method. Take the method beginning time at the beginning of the method. Take the method ending time at the end of the method. Print how much milliseconds the method took. You will see that the time does not change considerably at all even if you run it for several minutes.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    long methodBeginTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //<< Added this line.
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
    float x=255;
    int count=255;
    while(count!=0)
    {
        color=color+dir;
        if(color%128==0)
           dir=-dir;
        Color temp_color=new Color(color+64,0,0);
        Line2D line=new Line2D.Double(0.0,x,sz.width,x);
        g2.setPaint(temp_color);
        x--;
        count--;
        g2.draw(line);
    }
    long methodEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //<< Added this line.
    System.out.println("Method time:" + (methodEndTime - methodBeginTime)); //<< Added this line.
}
```

Then the question is - why does the wave does not progress in the same rate? Looks like the painting algorithm is creating the illusion of wave slowing down. It may be a combination of interaction of existing pattern being overwritten, screen refresh frequency etc. You may consider clearing the background before painting every time. Use double buffering to make it smoother. Hopefully these 2 things will improve the situation!

Comment: Hi, if i want to do something similar to my code above(tight loop, or constantly changing the color), is there a better class for the case?

Comment: Unfortunately no. To repeat it again - Color creation is not slowing you down. Other processing you may be doing is likely to be the reason for slow down. Please look at other parts of the code to find out the reason of slow down.

Comment: I also use a timer class to invoke the process

Comment: Looks like you are drawing 255 lines. That should not run slowly on recent hardware. Why do you feel it is slow?

Comment: well when I actually ran it it was fast at first. But after few waves it starts to slow down

Comment: What do you mean by "starts to slow down"? How do you know it is slowing down? Please give more details about how did you detect/decide it is slow?

Comment: I didn't actually set a timing variable to test the speed. but it's visibly slowed down when the program is run

Comment: The speed of the edge reaching the top of the window is slowing down for sure

Comment: @kmes40505 avoid writing too many comments in succession. Just copy them all and submit a new comment then delete the others.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but you would have to override the Color class. Below is an example of how to do so, but be warned; this is very unsafe for threads.

The following test is a very minimal and easy to read example that override the `Color` class and add functionality to set the individual color channels. The `ColorPanel` contains a function that if called, will loop infinitely until the user closes the window. While looping, the program will step through states decrementing the current R, G, or B channel until the value for that channel is zero then it moves to the next one. This only uses one `Color` object.

You can inspect all the code for the Color class here: [***java.awt.Color@grepcode.com***](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Color.java#Color)

**ColorPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ColorPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2243743609739642647L;

    private MyColor color;
    private int state, r, g, b;

    public ColorPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

        color = new MyColor(0xFF0000);
        state = 0;
        r = 255;
        g = 0;
        b = 0;
    }

    public void shitJustGotReal() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                switch (state) {
                    case 0:
                        r -= 0xF;
                        if (r < 0) { r = 0; state = 1; g = 0xFF; }
                        color.setRed(r);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        g -= 0xF;
                        if (g < 0) { g = 0; state = 2; b = 0xFF; }
                        color.setGreen(g);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        b -= 0xF;
                        if (b < 0) { b = 0; state = 0; r = 0xFF; }
                        color.setBlue(b);
                        break;
                }

                repaint();

                System.out.printf("%06X\n", color.getRGB());

                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Chessboard");
        ColorPanel c = new ColorPanel();

        f.setContentPane(c);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

        c.shitJustGotReal();
    }
}
```

**MyColor.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class MyColor extends Color {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6892714783307773362L;

    protected int value;

    public MyColor(int rgb) {
        super(rgb);

        value = 0xFF000000 | rgb;
    }

    public MyColor(int r, int g, int b) {
        this(r, g, b, 0xFF);
    }

    public MyColor(int r, int g, int b, int a) {
        super(r, g, b, a);

        setARGB(a, r, g, b);
    }

    public void setRed(int r) {
        setRGB(r, getGreen(), getBlue());
    }

    public void setGreen(int g) {
        setRGB(getRed(), g, getBlue());
    }

    public void setBlue(int b) {
        setRGB(getRed(), getGreen(), b);
    }

    public void setARGB(int a, int r, int g, int b) {
        value = ((a & 0xFF) << 24) |
                ((r & 0xFF) << 16) |
                ((g & 0xFF) <<  8) |
                ((b & 0xFF) <<  0);
    }

    public void setRGB(int r, int g, int b) {
        setARGB(0xFF, r, g, b);
    }

    public void setRGB(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRGB() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be that the `Color` to which you keep a reference are not fast enough cleaned up. So rather than creation taking to long I would consider you are using an ever greater partition of your memory for you colors.
One approach would be to create an array for the `Color`s and keep all 256 instances (at least it seams you code only loops around that few) which removes the need to create any `Color`s during your loop and keeps memory usage at a minimum.

A second approach of which I don't know whether or not it is a good idea, is that you can extend `Color` like this

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;

/**
 * Extends Color so the value can be changed. As the original value-field is only accessible from
 * within java.awt package we override {@link #getRGB()} which is used to access the value even in
 * functions like {@link #getRed()}.
 */
public class VaryingColor extends Color {
    public static final int ALPHA_PATTERN = 0xff000000;
    public static final int RED_PATTERN   = 0x00ff0000;
    public static final int GREEN_PATTERN = 0x0000ff00;
    public static final int BLUE_PATTERN  = 0x000000ff;

    public static final int ALPHA_OFFSET = 24;
    public static final int RED_OFFSET   = 16;
    public static final int GREEN_OFFSET = 8;
    public static final int BLUE_OFFSET  = 0;
    /**
     * ARGB encoded. In hex it is two digits each.
     */
    private int rgb;

    public VaryingColor(int r, int g, int b) {
        super(r, g, b);
        rgb = super.getRGB();
    }

    public VaryingColor(int r, int g, int b, int a) {
        super(r, g, b, a);
        rgb = super.getRGB();
    }

    public VaryingColor(int rgb) {
        super(rgb);
        rgb = super.getRGB();
    }

    public VaryingColor(int rgba, boolean hasalpha) {
        super(rgba, hasalpha);
        rgb = super.getRGB();
    }

    public VaryingColor(float r, float g, float b) {
        super(r, g, b);
        rgb = super.getRGB();
    }

    public VaryingColor(float r, float g, float b, float a) {
        super(r, g, b, a);
        rgb = super.getRGB();
    }

    public VaryingColor(ColorSpace cspace, float[] components, float alpha) {
        super(cspace, components, alpha);
        rgb = super.getRGB();
    }


    /**
     * Returns the RGB value representing the color in the default sRGB
     * {@link java.awt.image.ColorModel}.
     * (Bits 24-31 are alpha, 16-23 are red, 8-15 are green, 0-7 are
     * blue).
     */
    @Override
    public int getRGB() {
        return rgb;
    }

    public void setRGB(final int rgb) {
        this.rgb = rgb;
    }

    public void setAlpha(final int alpha) {
        this.setRGB((this.getRGB() & (~ALPHA_PATTERN)) | ((alpha & 0xFF) << ALPHA_OFFSET));
    }

    public void setRed(final int red) {
        this.setRGB((this.getRGB() & (~RED_PATTERN)) | ((red & 0xFF) << RED_OFFSET));
    }

    public void setGreen(final int green) {
        this.setRGB((this.getRGB() & (~GREEN_PATTERN)) | ((green & 0xFF) << GREEN_OFFSET));
    }

    public void setBlue(final int blue) {
        this.setRGB((this.getRGB() & (~BLUE_PATTERN)) | ((blue & 0xFF) << BLUE_OFFSET));
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell all functions in `Color` use `getRGB()` to access the value. Most probably to support the other classes derived from `Color` in setting the value.

I guess nothing will break when you use this, but I won't take any guarantees.

Comment: "It can be that the Color to which you keep a reference are not fast enough cleaned up." - is not correct. Modern JVMs with generational GC can easily cleanup local variables. Also, just returning from the method will cleanup all the variables created in the method. So it us unlikely to cause any problem.

Comment: The moment the Color is passed on we loose track of who is holding references unto the object. While the GC may be able to keep up I regard it a good idea to store the small palette needed for this function.

Comment: GC can track the object wherever it is in the JVM - so that is not the problem. In this particular case caching Color instances will help reduce some object instantiation and GC. However, none of them are causing any significant problem in this code. As I have demonstrated paint cycle runs in 0-1 millisecond on a i5 processor. Paint cycles completing in less than 30-40 milliseconds are not at all problem because that allows us to repaint the screen at least 25 times a second surpassing persistence of vision. Whatever problem kmes40505 has observed has got nothing to do with painting.

Comment: @RaviH if the called function stores a reference GC won't eleminate it  that's all i wanted to say. Otherwise I agree with you that 25 times are enough. Maybe some process is calling the function a second time?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from all the situations answered above, i found the main reason slowing down the pic is that I didn't add frame.remove(JComponent) function before adding a new component. This means the old one still exists and every time pack is called, both the new and old JComponents will be run(I used a static variable to control the waves, so the static component is run more than once in a pack()).